# Correct syntax for concatenating multiple ENV in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have 3 ENV Variables, that somehow are dependent on each other.

I found both syntaxes below to be not working and I am not able to find correct sytax also, Can someone please help me ?

```
ENV_1=/path/
ENV_2="$ENV_1"/dir2
ENV_3="$ENV_2"/dir3


ENV_1=/path/
ENV_2=$ENV_1/dir2
ENV_3=$ENV_2/dir3
```

Comment: This works for the `.env` file and also for `env_files` in docker-compose. AFAIK you can't do it in a `Dockerfile` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are declared with the `ENV` statement in Dockerfiles.
You can try the following approach

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

ENV parent=parent_dir
ENV child=child_dir

WORKDIR /tmp

#create nested dir structure in /tmp
RUN mkdir -p $parent\/$child
```

After you build the image and start the container , you will have the following structure inside the container:

```
/ # tree /tmp/
/tmp/
└── parent_dir
    └── child_dir
```